# Swaggerhub returns predefined response, but server stub doesn't

Tags: python, swagger, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator, swaggerhub

I have API yaml specification that defines what should be the response from each endpoint, e.g. I want that `/version` returns `version1.0` as defined:

```
openapi: "3.0.3"
info:
  title: "TITLE"
  description: "DESCRIPTION"
  version: "1.0.0"
paths:
  /version:
    get:      
      description: "description"      
      responses:
        "200": 
          description: "description"
          content: 
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/version'
components:
  schemas:
    version:
      type: object
      properties:
        version:
          type: string
      example:
        "version": "version1.0"
```

API server that runs on Swaggerhub works like expected, but e.g. python-flask server stub generated by Swaggerhub and run locally on my machine returns `do some magic!` for every endpoint and not the `example` provided in yaml. The same with server stubs generated using swagger-codegen and openapi-generator.

I am mainly interested in making it work for openapi-generator generated server stub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working as expected.

The `example` tag is an OpenAPI tag to provide an example object or schema to your users to demonstrate the use of your APIs. The virtual service provided by SwaggerHub (`virtserver`) is able to interpret `example` value and return these values when you make API calls to virtualized service provided by SwaggerHub.

On the other hand, codegen may or may not handle `example` tags in the same way (it depends on the codegen template). I have two recommendations about how to go about resolving this:

1. Add the example return values yourself. The codegen is not meant to be a complete solution, it's meant to be a jumping off point for development. Once you've generated the code, implement and add in your own business logic.
2. Create your own codegen template. This is a popular option for anyone who needs Swagget codegen to do something that isn't currently supported: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/wiki/Building-your-own-Templates